# load datagrid when select tab, easyui

Tags: jquery, jquery-easyui

I have a panel whit 4 tab, when i click a tab, i want to load the data to datagrid.
i put generic names
this is my code:

```
function create_datagrid() {
$('#grid_name').datagrid({
    url: "some url",
    title: 'Table',
    singleSelect: 'true',
    columns: [[
            {field: 'id', title: 'ID', with : 100, hidden: true},
            {field: 'fabricante', title: 'Nombre', with : 100, sortable:true}
        ]]
    });
}

$('#tt').tabs({
    onSelect: function (title) {
        $("#grid_name").ready(function () {

            create_datagrid();

      });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
       $('#tt').tabs({
            onSelect: function (title) {
                if (title == 'title1'){ //title tab 1
                    $('#grid_name1').datagrid('reload');
                }
                if (title == 'title2'){ //title tab 2
                    $('#grid_name2').datagrid('reload');
                }
                //and so on...
        });
```